# Recv not returning enough bytes (binary http response)?

Tags: c++, bittorrent

I am writing a bittorrent client in C++. When my program contacts the tracker using the info provided in the .torrent file, it sometimes doesn't send enough bytes back. The response, as defined by the bittorrent protocol specification ( http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_Response ), should be a bencoded dictionary, which means it should start with a 'd' and end with an 'e'. Here is the code I am using to receive and store the tracker response:

```
int iResult;
char recvBuf[512];
int recvBuflen = 512;
string response;

//Receive response from tracker
do{
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvBuf, recvBuflen, 0);
    if(iResult > 0){
        printf("  - Bytes Received: %d\n", iResult);
        response.append(recvBuf, 0, iResult);
    } else if(iResult == 0){
        printf("  - Connection Closed\n");
    } else {
        working = false;
        printf("  - Failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
} while(iResult > 0);
```

and here is what is in the response string when I look in the Watch feature in Visual Studio (after the connection has been closed):

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>   Content-Length: 399
>   d8:completei213e10:downloadedi139e10:incompletei17e8:intervali1970e12:min intervali985e5:peers300:Yšqö*^ýåÈµµcü*—®€Éýò6¸VÉ_0ºàÉQªUºÉÆ'÷ºÉQñ½ÎÃ¢V¬ãß¾Ã,Ië{¾£é´ÈÕ½ÇMÈn½ÖQÖ¼1¼K]»k„ÎÅº×
>   PÅº|Á¶X¼ºMä¸B"‹žÆ²”Œ2œ±ªÈj°4Ìú·¯«ö'î¯+r€c¯‰“r¦Î­´Ã7Íœ"5Ä­cÿICÈ|´"”ø3yÛæÜâÕsø¿³©nŸ¤u±ýmÿ‡µmš8äScûÜ8ý–_÷

The 300 after peers means that the data following 300: should be 300 bytes long. I put the data in a character counter and there was only 212 characters (bytes) which leads me to believe that the response was cut off. It also does not end in an e.

This only seems to happen when there is binary data involved. Is it possible that the binary data contained the binary for the '\0' character which caused it to be cut off prematurely? How would I fix that? Thank you :)

Comment: You shouldn't store binary data in a string (although you can). Use vector<char> instead.

Comment: Alex: no, use `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: Doesn't matter, unless you're going to be printing the bytes as numbers. Binary data is just binary data.

Comment: @Alex you don't want a negative `char` to accidentally get sign extended into an `int`.

Comment: How you treat binary data depends on its format. If you're supposed to do arithmetic with individual bytes, then _maybe_ you should treat them as unsigned chars and it's convenient to store them this way. But you may need to treat them as signed integers in the range -127 +128. More often than not you either cast the data to some `struct` or just pass it to some external function that can make sense of it. Either way, how you store it is not important as long as you treat it the right way at the point of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could simply be that the debugger displays the string until up to the first null char. You could consider using a `vector<unsigned char>` instead since you are dealing with raw bytes here.

Comment: This seems like the most likely option. After seeing your answer, I ran a few more tests in visual studio. recv told me it had retrieved 466 bytes of data, and I checked how many characters (bytes) visual studio was showing me and it was 207. That should've been one of the things I checked earlier :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's just a printing issue: check the actual string `length()` and print String's `data()` manually (i.e. with a loop). As you said, it's entirely possible that Visual Studio stops displaying the string in the watch list as soon as the first `\0` is encountered.